# MultiProject Gradle Build that will analyze the Parent Project?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a multi-project gradle build that I am attempting to use sonarqube to analyze.  It successfully analyzes all the nested modules in the project but doesn't analyze the base or parent project.

I see this warning in the logs:

> 12:07:23.332 WARN  - /!\ A multi-module project can't have source folders, so 'C:\workspaces\platform\myProject\src\main\java' won't be used for the analysis. If you want to analyse files of this folder, you should create another sub-module and move them inside it.

Is there a way to move the parent src, test, and binary as folders to be scanned with out creating submodule out of the parent?

My SonarQube properties look like this:

```
sonarqube{
properties {
    property "sonar.host.url", "http://ww:80"
    property "sonar.jdbc.url", "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://db:5555;databaseName=sonarqube"
    property "sonar.jdbc.driverClassName", "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
    property "sonar.jdbc.username", "u"
    property "sonar.jdbc.password", "p"
    property "sonar.scm.disabled", "true"  
    property "sonar.junit.reportsPath", "${buildDir}/test-results"     
    property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "${buildDir}/jacoco/test.exec"
    property "sonar.modules" , ""  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a well known limitation of SonarQube. You can follow/vote for: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARGRADL-5

Comment: Thanks!  Good to know it has potential to be modified.

Is there a way around it in the mean time?  

Can the source of parent be added to sonar.modules?  I have not been successful at getting this to work.

Is it possible to just skip all the sub modules and just scan the parent?

Comment: To skip all submodules you can probably override property sonar.modules to blank. But then you are on your own to pass all correct properties (sonar.sources, sonar.tests, sonar.java.binaries, ...)

Comment: I have been attempting to override the sonar.modules to blank, but nothing seems to change.  
I looked here and didn't find a "sonar.modules".  Is there a different param I should be updating?  I updated my question with the sonarqube properties block I am using

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters

Comment: Do you mean passing blank sonar.modules continue to analyze sub-modules?

Comment: Yes.   Setting this property in my gradle script -- property "sonar.modules" , ""  --   seems to have no effect.

Comment: Strange. Could you examine output of ./gradlew sonarque -DsonarRunner.dumpToFile=out.txt to see if property sonar.modules is correctly set to empty?

Comment: It was not set to empty.   It still lists all the subprojects.

Just for clarification, I am using sonarqube gradle command and not sonar-runner.

I am also trying to run this out of the SpringSourceToolSuite IDE

Comment: Hum, in fact maybe it is not possible to override a property with a blank value. As a last try could you pass it on command line: `./gradlew sonarqube "-Dsonar.modules= "`

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and solved it for the current [Sonarqube Scanner for Gradle](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-gradle) and Gradle 3.

See https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/argelbargel.gradle.plugins.sonarqube-multiproject-plugin. It basically detects projects with sub-projects and source-code and modifies the internal properties of the sonarqube-Task.

The plugin is based on the [solution](https://github.com/hallatech/gradle-sonar-multi-atg-project) mentioned in the [old gradle forum](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-apply-sonar-runner-to-multi-project-hierarchies-with-code-in-the-root-project/7369/10).